# Display attribute image instead of text

Tags: magento, attributes, branding

I figure out how to show attribute in category of product list, what I need is to display an image instead of text.

Eg. I have an attribute text `ASUS` and a image located in `media/brands/` named `asus.gif` or instead of `Western-Digital` display image located in `media/brands/western-digital.gif`.

I hope you understand

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getMediaUrl(); ?>brands/<?php echo strtolower($_product->getManufacturer()); ?>.png" />
```

getManufacturer may be the attribte, change it, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
 <?php $brand=$_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
    echo '<a href="/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$brand).'"><img style="float: right; margin: 2px;" src="/media/catalog/brands/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$brand).'.gif" alt="'.$brand.'"></a>' ?>
```

Comment: you should use $this->getMediaUrl() instead of "/media/". It doesn't cost you anything, but a lot of work if you move the shop some time to a subdirectory!

Comment: Hey @LuckyDaniel , maybe you can tell me how to make it an if? So if the image doesn't exist then display text? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If your attribute is a dropdown one you could add a new column in the table eav_attribute_option_value and in the "manage options/labels" tab of the manage attribute page in the admin panel. For each option values, next to each store traduction, you could store the name of your image and retrieve it in your templates.. it require some development but it's doable and easy to administrate.

Or the quick and dirty way : use the admin label string, lowercase it and clean to retrieve an image related filename

Comment: Can you be more specific?  I will be grateful .. help me to understand the first way please..

Answer (score 0):

In the Magento 1.7.0.2 you can accomplish this in a very easy way...

All you do is create a new attribute, and select 'media image' from the 'catalog input type..' dropdown.